# Get call hierarchy with own eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am currently developping an eclipse plugin, which shall be capable to analyze code in a special way.
Right now, i would need a possibility to return the call hierarchy of a function for further procession. I know, there already is a way to view the call hierarchy in eclipse, but i want to have the raw data (like using an interface to retrieve this call hierarchy and further refine it my own way).
Is there any interface or api for that?

Comment: Assuming you are asking about Java read about the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: this could indeed help me, i will check that... thx :)